# With Swift how to implement drag and connect

Tags: macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

[image: Drag and connect]

As in Xcode, you connect your UI elements to code blocks by *ctrl+dragging* them. Above image shows such a *drag and connect* operation (see the blu line with the arrow).

I am working on a very simple **mac osx app**, where i have to deal with this kind of connections a lot; need some starting point for this one.

How should go about this, is there a lib or pod that helps any information would be helpful.

Any Details on how to draw Connector threads and Nodes would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,Unfortunately, I'm really busy at the moment, so I can't supply a full answer. I do have an OS X app that uses this UI pattern, maybe it will help:  https://github.com/FlexMonkey/sweetcorn

Comment: Do you just want to draw the arrows?

Comment: hey @johnelemans, thanks for checking this, I am looking for some guidance on how to implement the drag and connect operation like seen here https://youtu.be/vFrivX021-A?t=16s

Comment: I looked up my own code but it is wildly out of date. This shows the basics; http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/11/30/cocoa.html The key trick is to implement MouseDragged handlers which draw your line while the mouse is being moved.

Comment: **Basic way to do it could be:**

Get the reference of drag source as drag operation begins. 
---
Use CoreGraphic to Draw a _**Line (bezier curve)**_ originating from drag source and connecting it to the current position of Mouse Pointer.
---
Move one end of  _**Line (bezier curve)**_  which is connected to mouse pointer as the user moves the pointer.
---
Hit testing references of drop destinations simultaneously to know if the drop is valid on the object mouse pointer is hovering currently.
---
Once the user drops and completes the operation. You have your Source and Destination.

Comment: I guess I know the algo, but I am having a hard time implementing the above in swift code and OSX way of doing things, Where to begin? any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reproduce this Xcode blue drag line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688437/how-to-reproduce-this-xcode-blue-drag-line)