# How to reproduce this Xcode blue drag line

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-graphics

I'd like to reproduce the Xcode blue drag line in my app.

Do you know a way to code this ?

[image: Xcode blue drag line]

I know how to draw a line using Core Graphics ...
But this line has to be over the top of all other items (on the screen).

Comment: Making a line should be pretty simple - add an invisible layer or view on top of everything and just draw the line. (At least this is one way.) But making the line draw intelligently (from one specific point on a view beneath it to another such point), or making various actions on the views beneath this invisible view receive those actions will take a lot.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! Well, how do you add an invisible layer on top of everything (even other apps) ?

Comment: Other apps? I don't know.Your question never said that, and Xcode is a single app. I did note you tagged this a Cocoa so I'm assuming you are asking about macOS where you have separate windows. But even there, the only time developers were able to "draw a blue line" in Xcode was IIRC version 5 when they gave the app a "unified" window.  As I said in my first comment - the *easy* piece is that layer. (1) Take a single or unified window with subviews for a file hierarchy, code editor, toolbar, etc. Add - on top of it all - another subview to draw on.

Comment: It is not what I am looking for. In Xcode, the blue line can go even outside the app. In my second screenshot, there is Xcode in left and Chrome in right, and the blue line is over the two apps. And I said : "over the top of all other items (on the screen)." On the screen means all the apps opened + the desktop.
I just found a way to do it, with an invisible NSWindow ! I will be posting my code when I finish

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm posting this after you've posted your own answer, so this is probably a huge waste of time. But your answer only covers drawing a really bare-bones line on the screen and doesn't cover a bunch of other interesting stuff that you need to take care of to really replicate Xcode's behavior and even go beyond it:

- drawing a nice connection line like Xcode's (with a shadow, an outline, and big rounded ends),
- drawing the line across multiple screens,
- using Cocoa drag and drop to find the drag target and to support spring-loading.

Here's a demo of what I'm going to explain in this answer:

[image: demo]

[In this github repo](https://github.com/mayoff/dragLine), you can find an Xcode project containing all the code in this answer plus the remaining glue code necessary to run a demo app.

### Drawing a nice connection line like Xcode's

Xcode's connection line looks like an [old-timey barbell](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=old-timey+barbell). It has a straight bar of arbitrary length, with a circular bell at each end:

[image: basic shape]

What do we know about that shape? The user provides the start and end points (the centers of the bells) by dragging the mouse, and our user interface designer specifies the radius of the bells and the thickness of the bar:

[image: givens]

The length of the bar is the distance from `startPoint` to `endPoint`: `length = hypot(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, endPoint.y - startPoint.y)`.

To simplify the process of creating a path for this shape, let's draw it in a standard pose, with the left bell at the origin and the bar parallel to the x axis. In this pose, here's what we know:

[image: givens at origin]

We can create this shape as a path by making a circular arc centered at the origin, connected to another (mirror image) circular arc centered at `(length, 0)`. To create these arcs, we need this `mysteryAngle`:

[image: mystery angle]

We can figure out `mysteryAngle` if we can find any of the arc endpoints where the bell meets the bar. Specifically, we'll find the coordinates of this point:

[image: mystery point]

What do we know about that `mysteryPoint`? We know it's at the intersection of the bell and the top of the bar. So we know it's at distance `bellRadius` from the origin, and at distance `barThickness / 2` from the x axis:

[image: mystery point givens]

So immediately we know that `mysteryPoint.y = barThickness / 2`, and we can use the Pythagorean theorem to compute `mysteryPoint.x = sqrt(bellRadius² - mysteryPoint.y²)`.

With `mysteryPoint` located, we can compute `mysteryAngle` using our choice of inverse trigonometry function. Arcsine, I choose you! `mysteryAngle = asin(mysteryPoint.y / bellRadius)`.

We now know everything we need to create the path in the standard pose. To move it from the standard pose to the desired pose (which goes from `startPoint` to `endPoint`, remember?), we'll apply an affine transform. The transform will translate (move) the path so the left bell is centered at `startPoint` and rotate the path so the right bell ends up at `endPoint`.

In writing the code to create the path, we want to be careful of a few things:

- What if the length is so short that the bells overlap? We should handle that gracefully by adjusting `mysteryAngle` so the bells connect seamlessly with no weird “negative bar” between them.
- What if `bellRadius` is smaller than `barThickness / 2`? We should handle that gracefully by forcing `bellRadius` to be at least `barThickness / 2`.
- What if `length` is zero? We need to avoid division by zero.

Here's my code to create the path, handling all those cases:

```
extension CGPath {
    class func barbell(from start: CGPoint, to end: CGPoint, barThickness proposedBarThickness: CGFloat, bellRadius proposedBellRadius: CGFloat) -> CGPath {
        let barThickness = max(0, proposedBarThickness)
        let bellRadius = max(barThickness / 2, proposedBellRadius)

        let vector = CGPoint(x: end.x - start.x, y: end.y - start.y)
        let length = hypot(vector.x, vector.y)

        if length == 0 {
            return CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: start, size: .zero).insetBy(dx: -bellRadius, dy: -bellRadius), transform: nil)
        }

        var yOffset = barThickness / 2
        var xOffset = sqrt(bellRadius * bellRadius - yOffset * yOffset)
        let halfLength = length / 2
        if xOffset > halfLength {
            xOffset = halfLength
            yOffset = sqrt(bellRadius * bellRadius - xOffset * xOffset)
        }

        let jointRadians = asin(yOffset / bellRadius)
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addArc(center: .zero, radius: bellRadius, startAngle: jointRadians, endAngle: -jointRadians, clockwise: false)
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: length, y: 0), radius: bellRadius, startAngle: .pi + jointRadians, endAngle: .pi - jointRadians, clockwise: false)
        path.closeSubpath()

        let unitVector = CGPoint(x: vector.x / length, y: vector.y / length)
        var transform = CGAffineTransform(a: unitVector.x, b: unitVector.y, c: -unitVector.y, d: unitVector.x, tx: start.x, ty: start.y)
        return path.copy(using: &transform)!
    }
}
```

Once we have the path, we need to fill it with the correct color, stroke it with the correct color and line width, and draw a shadow around it. I used Hopper Disassembler on `IDEInterfaceBuilderKit` to figure out Xcode's exact sizes and colors. Xcode draws it all into a graphics context in a custom view's `drawRect:`, but we'll make our custom view use a `CAShapeLayer`. We won't end up drawing the shadow *precisely* the same as Xcode, but it's close enough.

```
class ConnectionView: NSView {
    struct Parameters {
        var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        var endPoint = CGPoint.zero
        var barThickness = CGFloat(2)
        var ballRadius = CGFloat(3)
    }

    var parameters = Parameters() { didSet { needsLayout = true } }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer { return shapeLayer }

    override func layout() {
        super.layout()

        shapeLayer.path = CGPath.barbell(from: parameters.startPoint, to: parameters.endPoint, barThickness: parameters.barThickness, bellRadius: parameters.ballRadius)
        shapeLayer.shadowPath = CGPath.barbell(from: parameters.startPoint, to: parameters.endPoint, barThickness: parameters.barThickness + shapeLayer.lineWidth / 2, bellRadius: parameters.ballRadius + shapeLayer.lineWidth / 2)
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        wantsLayer = true

        shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinMiter
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.75
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 209/360, saturation: 0.83, brightness: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
        shapeLayer.shadowColor = NSColor.selectedControlColor.blended(withFraction: 0.2, of: .black)?.withAlphaComponent(0.85).cgColor
        shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 3
        shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        shapeLayer.shadowOffset = .zero
    }
}
```

We can test this in a playground to make sure it looks good:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = NSView()
view.setFrameSize(CGSize(width: 400, height: 200))
view.wantsLayer = true
view.layer!.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

for i: CGFloat in stride(from: 0, through: 9, by: CGFloat(0.4)) {
    let connectionView = ConnectionView(frame: view.bounds)
    connectionView.parameters.startPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * 40 + 15, y: 50)
    connectionView.parameters.endPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * 40 + 15, y: 50 + CGFloat(i))
    view.addSubview(connectionView)
}

let connectionView = ConnectionView(frame: view.bounds)
connectionView.parameters.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100)
connectionView.parameters.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 350, y: 150)
view.addSubview(connectionView)
```

Here's the result:

[image: playground result]

### Drawing across multiple screens

If you have multiple screens (displays) attached to your Mac, and if you have “Displays have separate Spaces” turned on (which is the default) in the Mission Control panel of your System Preferences, then macOS will not let a window span two screens. This means that you can't use a single window to draw the connecting line across multiple monitors. This matters if you want to let the user connect an object in one window to an object in another window, like Xcode does:

Here's the checklist for drawing the line, across multiple screens, on top of our other windows:

- We need to create one window per screen.
- We need to set up each window to fill its screen and be completely transparent with no shadow.
- We need to set the window level of each window to 1 to keep it above our normal windows (which have a window level of 0).
- We need to tell each window **not** to release itself when closed, because we don't like mysterious autorelease pool crashes.
- Each window needs its own `ConnectionView`.
- To keep the coordinate systems uniform, we'll adjust the `bounds` of each `ConnectionView` so that its coordinate system matches the screen coordinate system.
- We'll tell each `ConnectionView` to draw the entire connecting line; each view will clip what it draws to its own bounds.
- It probably won't happen, but we'll arrange to be notified if the screen arrangement changes. If that happens, we'll add/remove/update windows to cover the new arrangement.

Let's make a class to encapsulate all these details. With an instance of `LineOverlay`, we can update the start and end points of the connection as needed, and remove the overlay from the screen when we're done.

```
class LineOverlay {

    init(startScreenPoint: CGPoint, endScreenPoint: CGPoint) {
        self.startScreenPoint = startScreenPoint
        self.endScreenPoint = endScreenPoint

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LineOverlay.screenLayoutDidChange(_:)), name: .NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParameters, object: nil)
        synchronizeWindowsToScreens()
    }

    var startScreenPoint: CGPoint { didSet { setViewPoints() } }

    var endScreenPoint: CGPoint { didSet { setViewPoints() } }

    func removeFromScreen() {
        windows.forEach { $0.close() }
        windows.removeAll()
    }

    private var windows = [NSWindow]()

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        removeFromScreen()
    }

    @objc private func screenLayoutDidChange(_ note: Notification) {
        synchronizeWindowsToScreens()
    }

    private func synchronizeWindowsToScreens() {
        var spareWindows = windows
        windows.removeAll()
        for screen in NSScreen.screens() ?? [] {
            let window: NSWindow
            if let index = spareWindows.index(where: { $0.screen === screen}) {
                window = spareWindows.remove(at: index)
            } else {
                let styleMask = NSWindowStyleMask.borderless
                window = NSWindow(contentRect: .zero, styleMask: styleMask, backing: .buffered, defer: true, screen: screen)
                window.contentView = ConnectionView()
                window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
                window.ignoresMouseEvents = true
            }
            windows.append(window)
            window.setFrame(screen.frame, display: true)

            // Make the view's geometry match the screen geometry for simplicity.
            let view = window.contentView!
            var rect = view.bounds
            rect = view.convert(rect, to: nil)
            rect = window.convertToScreen(rect)
            view.bounds = rect

            window.backgroundColor = .clear
            window.isOpaque = false
            window.hasShadow = false
            window.isOneShot = true
            window.level = 1

            window.contentView?.needsLayout = true
            window.orderFront(nil)
        }

        spareWindows.forEach { $0.close() }
    }

    private func setViewPoints() {
        for window in windows {
            let view = window.contentView! as! ConnectionView
            view.parameters.startPoint = startScreenPoint
            view.parameters.endPoint = endScreenPoint
        }
    }

}
```

### Using Cocoa drag and drop to find the drag target and perform spring-loading

We need a way to find the (potential) drop target of the connection as the user drags the mouse around. It would also be nice to support spring loading.

In case you don't know, spring loading is a macOS feature in which, if you hover a drag over a container for a moment, macOS will automatically open the container without interrupting the drag. Examples:

- If you drag onto a window that's not the frontmost window, macOS will bring the window to the front.
- if you drag onto a Finder folder icon, and the Finder will open the folder window to let you drag onto an item in the folder.
- If you drag onto a tab handle (at the top of the window) in Safari or Chrome, the browser will select the tab, letting you drop your item in the tab.
- If you control-drag a connection in Xcode onto a menu item in the menu bar in your storyboard or xib, Xcode will open the item's menu.

If we use the standard Cocoa drag and drop support to track the drag and find the drop target, then we'll get spring loading support “for free”.

To support standard Cocoa drag and drop, we need to implement the `NSDraggingSource` protocol on some object, so we can drag *from* something, and the `NSDraggingDestination` protocol on some other object, so we can drag *to* something. We'll implement `NSDraggingSource` in a class called `ConnectionDragController`, and we'll implement `NSDraggingDestination` in a custom view class called `DragEndpoint`.

First, let's look at `DragEndpoint` (an `NSView` subclass). `NSView` already conforms to `NSDraggingDestination`, but doesn't do much with it. We need to implement four methods of the `NSDraggingDestination` protocol. The drag session will call these methods to let us know when the drag enters and leaves the destination, when the drag ends entirely, and when to “perform” the drag (assuming this destination was where the drag actually ended). We also need to register the type of dragged data that we can accept.

We want to be careful of two things:

- We only want to accept a drag that is a connection attempt. We can figure out whether a drag is a connection attempt by checking whether the source is our custom drag source, `ConnectionDragController`.
- We'll make `DragEndpoint` appear to be the drag source (visually only, not programmatically). We don't want to let the user connect an endpoint to itself, so we need to make sure the endpoint that is the source of the connection cannot also be used as the target of the connection. We'll do that using a `state` property that tracks whether this endpoint is idle, acting as the source, or acting as the target.

When the user finally releases the mouse button over a valid drop destination, the drag session makes it the destination's responsibility to “perform” the drag by sending it `performDragOperation(_:)`. The session doesn't tell the drag source where the drop finally happened. But we probably want to do the work of making the connection (in our data model) back in the source. Think about how it works in Xcode: when you control-drag from a button in `Main.storyboard` to `ViewController.swift` and create an action, the connection is not recorded in `ViewController.swift` where the drag ended; it's recorded in `Main.storyboard`, as part of the button's persistent data. So when the drag session tells the destination to “perform” the drag, we'll make our destination (`DragEndpoint`) pass itself back to a `connect(to:)` method on the drag source where the real work can happen.

```
class DragEndpoint: NSView {

    enum State {
        case idle
        case source
        case target
    }

    var state: State = State.idle { didSet { needsLayout = true } }

    public override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        guard case .idle = state else { return [] }
        guard (sender.draggingSource() as? ConnectionDragController)?.sourceEndpoint != nil else { return [] }
        state = .target
        return sender.draggingSourceOperationMask()
    }

    public override func draggingExited(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        guard case .target = state else { return }
        state = .idle
    }

    public override func draggingEnded(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        guard case .target = state else { return }
        state = .idle
    }

    public override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        guard let controller = sender.draggingSource() as? ConnectionDragController else { return false }
        controller.connect(to: self)
        return true
    }

    override init(frame: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        wantsLayer = true
        register(forDraggedTypes: [kUTTypeData as String])
    }

    // Drawing code omitted here but is in my github repo.
}
```

Now we can implement `ConnectionDragController` to act as the drag source and to manage the drag session and the `LineOverlay`.

- To start a drag session, we have to call `beginDraggingSession(with:event:source:)` on a view; it'll be the `DragEndpoint` where the mouse-down event happened.
- The session notifies the source when the drag actually starts, when it moves, and when it ends. We use those notifications to create and update the `LineOverlay`.
- Since we're not providing any images as part of our `NSDraggingItem`, the session won't draw anything being dragged. This is good.
- By default, if the drag ends outside of a valid destination, the session will animate… nothing… back to the start of the drag, before notifying the source that the drag has ended. During this animation, the line overlay hangs around, frozen. It looks broken. We tell the session not to animate back to the start to avoid this.

Since this is just a demo, the “work” we do to connect the endpoints in `connect(to:)` is just printing their descriptions. In a real app, you'd actually modify your data model.

```
class ConnectionDragController: NSObject, NSDraggingSource {

    var sourceEndpoint: DragEndpoint?

    func connect(to target: DragEndpoint) {
        Swift.print("Connect \(sourceEndpoint!) to \(target)")
    }

    func trackDrag(forMouseDownEvent mouseDownEvent: NSEvent, in sourceEndpoint: DragEndpoint) {
        self.sourceEndpoint = sourceEndpoint
        let item = NSDraggingItem(pasteboardWriter: NSPasteboardItem(pasteboardPropertyList: "\(view)", ofType: kUTTypeData as String)!)
        let session = sourceEndpoint.beginDraggingSession(with: [item], event: mouseDownEvent, source: self)
        session.animatesToStartingPositionsOnCancelOrFail = false
    }

    func draggingSession(_ session: NSDraggingSession, sourceOperationMaskFor context: NSDraggingContext) -> NSDragOperation {
        switch context {
        case .withinApplication: return .generic
        case .outsideApplication: return []
        }
    }

    func draggingSession(_ session: NSDraggingSession, willBeginAt screenPoint: NSPoint) {
        sourceEndpoint?.state = .source
        lineOverlay = LineOverlay(startScreenPoint: screenPoint, endScreenPoint: screenPoint)
    }

    func draggingSession(_ session: NSDraggingSession, movedTo screenPoint: NSPoint) {
        lineOverlay?.endScreenPoint = screenPoint
    }

    func draggingSession(_ session: NSDraggingSession, endedAt screenPoint: NSPoint, operation: NSDragOperation) {
        lineOverlay?.removeFromScreen()
        sourceEndpoint?.state = .idle
    }

    func ignoreModifierKeys(for session: NSDraggingSession) -> Bool { return true }

    private var lineOverlay: LineOverlay?

}
```

That's all you need. As a reminder, you can find a link at the top of this answer to a github repo containing a complete demo project.

Comment: Such an amazing and inspiring answer. Thank you so much !

Comment: This is great. I cloned the repo and tried the app. On first launch of the demo app, drag wasn't working and I was getting `CoreDragCreate` errors in the console instead. This answer on AskDifferent solved it: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242111/coredragcreate-error-dragdrop-and-copy-paste-stop-working/243213

Comment: Weird.  I’ve never seen anything like that.

Comment: Now I'm **really** having trouble getting it to work on subviews of `NSOutlineView` (rows); `hittest()` just won't go above the outline view itself...

Comment: Hmm, looks like I need to override `mouseDown(with:)` on the outline view itself (the hosting view controller won't cut it when an outline view is involved), and then I need to navigate all the way to the appropriate cell using the outline view's API (`row(at:)`, `rowView(atRow:)`, etc.), but I finally got the blue line to appear! :-)

Comment: You may need to look at [`validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1527066-validateproposedfirstresponder?language=objc).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I've opened a can of worms here.

Comment: Returning `true` from the overriden `validateProposedFirstResponder` did the trick, and now `hittest()` returns the `DragEndpoint` subview. I'm still trying to figure out how to get springloading to work (expand dragged-over rows to access the `DragEndpoint` views within)...

Comment: This is embarrasing... Actually, springloading _is_ working; I just wasn't waiting long enough - the row views just don't provide any visual feedback (e.g., blinking) when they're about to expand. The problem I have now is, if the origin of the drag line is in a row _below_ the drop candidate, when the springloading kicks in and a row is expanded, the drag line's start position becomes outdated (offset)... But I think I can figure this myself with what I have so far. Thanks again!

Comment: Wow, very in depth answer; looks like an article. Top. Maybe you will like to write an in depth blog about Swift(ui) named "The In depth Blog". I wil subscribe.

Answer (score 3):

Using a transparent NSWindow :

[image]

```
var window: NSWindow!

func createLinePath(from: NSPoint, to: NSPoint) -> CGPath {
    let path = CGMutablePath()

    path.move(to: from)
    path.addLine(to: to)

    return path
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Transparent window
    window = NSWindow()
    window.styleMask = .borderless
    window.backgroundColor = .clear
    window.isOpaque = false
    window.hasShadow = false

    //Line
    let line = CAShapeLayer()

    line.path = createLinePath(from: NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0), to: NSPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    line.lineWidth = 10.0
    line.strokeColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor

    //Update
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved]) {
        let newPos = NSEvent.mouseLocation()

        line.path = self.createLinePath(from: NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0), to: newPos)

        return $0
    }

    window.contentView!.layer = line
    window.contentView!.wantsLayer = true

    window.setFrame(NSScreen.main()!.frame, display: true)

    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Trying to adopt [Rob Mayoff's excellent solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43699137/433373) into my own project's interface, which is based around an `NSOutlineView`, I ran into a few problems. In case it helps anyone trying to achieve the same thing, I'll detail those pitfalls in this answer.

The sample code provided in the solution detects the start of a drag by implementing `mouseDown(with:)` on the **view controller**, and then calling `hittest()` on the window's content view in order to obtain the `DragEndpoint` subview where the (potential) drag is originating. When using outline views, this causes two pitfalls detailed in the next sections.

#### 1. Mouse-Down Event

It seems that when a table view or outline view is involved, `mouseDown(with:)` never gets called on the view controller, and we need to instead override that method in the **outline view** itself.

#### 2. Hit Testing

`NSTableView` -and by extension, `NSOutlineView`- overrides the `NSResponder` method `validateProposedFirstResponder(_:for:)`, and this causes the `hittest()` method to fail: it always returns the outline view itself, and all subviews (including our target `DragEndpoint` subview inside the cell) remain inaccessible.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/RowSelection/RowSelection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH6-SW9):

> Views or controls in a table sometimes need to respond to incoming
>   events. To determine whether a particular subview should receive the
>   current mouse event, a table view calls
>   `validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent:` in its implementation of
>   `hitTest`. If you create a table view subclass, you can override
>   `validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent:` to specify which views can
>   become the first responder. In this way, you receive mouse events.

At first I tried overriding:

```
override func validateProposedFirstResponder(_ responder: NSResponder, for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
    if responder is DragEndpoint {
        return true
    }
    return super.validateProposedFirstResponder(responder, for: event)
}
```

...and it worked, but reading the documentation further suggests a smarter, less intrusive approach:

> The default `NSTableView` implementation of
>   `validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent:` uses the following logic:
>
> 1. **Return `YES` for all proposed first responder views unless they are
>      instances or subclasses of `NSControl`.**
> 2. Determine whether the proposed
>      first responder is an `NSControl` instance or subclass. If the control
>      is an `NSButton` object, return `YES`. If the control is not an `NSButton`,
>      call the control’s `hitTestForEvent:inRect:ofView:` to see whether the
>      hit area is trackable (that is, `NSCellHitTrackableArea`) or is an
>      editable text area (that is, `NSCellHitEditableTextArea`), and return
>      the appropriate value. Note that if a text area is hit, `NSTableView`
>      also delays the first responder action.

*(emphasis mine)*

...which is weird, because it feels like it should say:

> 1. Return **`NO`** for all proposed first responder views unless they are
>      instances or subclasses of `NSControl`.

, but anyway, I instead modified Rob's code to make `DragEndpoint` a subclass of `NSControl` (not just `NSView`), and that works too.

#### 3. Managing the Dragging Session

Because `NSOutlineView` only exposes a limited number of drag-and-drop events through its **data source** protocol (and the drag session itself can not be meaningfully modified from the data source's side), it seems that taking full control of the drag session is not possible unless we **subclass** the outline view and override the `NSDraggingSource` methods.
Only by overriding `draggingSession(_:willBeginAt:)` at the outline view itself can we prevent calling the superclass implementation and starting an actual item drag (which displays the dragged row image).

We could start a separate drag session from the `mouseDown(with:)` method of the `DragEndpoint` subview: when implemented, it is called *before* the same method on the outline view (which in turn is what triggers the dragging session to be started). But if we move the dragging session away from the outline view, it seems like it will be impossible to have **springloading** "for free" when dragging above an expandable item.

So instead, I discarded the `ConnectionDragController` class and moved all its logic to the outline view subclass: the `tackDrag()` method, the active `DragEndpoint` property, and all methods of the `NSDraggingSource` protocol into the outline view.

Ideally, I would have liked to avoid subclassing `NSOutlineView` (it is discouraged) and instead implement this behaviour more cleanly, exclusively through the outline view's delegate/data source and/or external classes (like the original `ConnectionDragController`), but it seems that it is impossible.

I haven't got the springloading part to work yet (it *was* working at a moment, but not now so I'm still looking into it...).

---

I too made a sample project, but I'm still fixing minor issues. I'll post a link  to the GiHub repository as soon as it is ready.